# React state changes but background does not change

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { tsParenthesizedType } from "@babel/types";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }

state = {
  bgcolor: ""
};

styleQuestion = {
  backgroundColor: this.state.bgcolor,
};

render() {
  return (
    <div style={this.styleQuestion}>
        <button
          onClick={this.myFunction}
        >
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}

myFunction() {
  this.setState({ bgcolor: "blue" });
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```

When I click the button, the state of bgcolor changes (I debugged it) but the background doesn't change. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix is probably to just move your style object into the `render` so that it gets re-declared each time state changes. As is, the property will not update without you manually doing so, its just getting set to the initial value of `this.state.bgcolor`.

Solution:

```js
render() {
  const styleQuestion = {
    backgroundColor: this.state.bgcolor,
  };
  return (
    <div style={styleQuestion}>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move

```
styleQuestion = {
    backgroundColor : this.state.bgColor,
};
```

inside a [component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) method that gets evaluated each time the component is re-rendered.  Currently, it will only be evaluated the first time the component is loaded, which is why it doesn't change the color of the div.  The simplest solution would be to move that line into the `Render` method.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off here making your state `undefined`.

Something like this:

```
state: {
  bgcolor: undefined
}

const { bgcolor: backgroundColour} = this.state;

<div style={{backgroundColor}}>
```

So here I am aliasing the state to the same property name as the css property. The benefit here is that if the change does not happen then noting gets rendered.

Otherwise you get the intended colour. It easy to read and keeps the style property fairly clean as this expression expects an object.

I would note if you wish to send in styles I would also tweak with `{{...this.props.style, backgroundColor}}` which would pass on the styles down but not override your background.